# Coil AsyncImage get larger after back stack

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have a screen that displays a list of image movies using AsyncImage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhSUh.jpg

When I click an item, the Detail screen will display with a full-screen image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd9se.jpg

And when I back stack to the first screen, the image gets large
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb80K.jpg

Here is the code that displays the image on the first screen

```
        AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.posterPath)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_movie_image)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
```

Here is the code that displays the image on the second screen

```
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.poster_path)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .error(R.drawable.default_movie_image)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.6f),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
```

I want the image on the first screen will keep the size as normal. Please help me

Answer (score -1):

Here are some possible solutions for your problem:

1. **Use a different image cache for the two screens.** This is probably the simplest and most effective solution. You can use a different instance of `ImageCache` for each screen, or you can use a library like `Coil` or `Glide` which provides more control over image caching.
2. **Manually resize the image on the second screen.** You can do this by using the `ImageResizer` class to resize the image before it is displayed.
3. **Use a different `AsyncImage` implementation.** There are a number of third-party `AsyncImage` implementations which provide more control over image caching and resizing. For example, the `Coil` library provides a `ImageCoil` class which allows you to specify a custom `ImageCache` and `ImageResizer`.

Here is an example of how to use a different image cache for the two screens:

```
class FirstScreen : Screen() {
    private val imageCache = ImageCache()

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.posterPath)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .error(R.drawable.default_movie_image)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            imageCache = imageCache
        )
    }
}

class SecondScreen : Screen() {
    private val imageCache = ImageCache()

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.poster_path)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .error(R.drawable.default_movie_image)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.6f),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            imageCache = imageCache
        )
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to manually resize the image on the second screen:

```
class SecondScreen : Screen() {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        val image = AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.poster_path)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
                .error(R.drawable.default_movie_image)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
        )

        val resizedImage = ImageResizer(image.bitmap).resize(width = 100, height = 100)

        Image(
            bitmap = resizedImage,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.6f),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to use the `Coil` library to display the image on the second screen:

```
class SecondScreen : Screen() {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        CoilImage(
            model = stringResource(id = R.string.base_image_url) + movie.poster_path,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(0.6f),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

Which solution you choose will depend on your specific needs and preferences. I recommend trying out a few different solutions to see what works best for you.